# Boolean array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, boolean

I have an one doubt with conditional array in php.

Here is my code,

```
foreach($orders as $order) {
array_push($list, array($order['name'],$order['email'],$order['buyer_accepts_marketing']));
}
```

Still now i got the value of $order['buyer_accepts_marketing'] is 1, but I want value as true.

I tried, but didn't get exact answer.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast your value as boolean (c.f. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php):

```
foreach($orders as $order) {
    array_push($list, array(
        $order['name'],
        $order['email'],
        (boolean) $order['buyer_accepts_marketing']
    ));
}
```

Just FYI, a shortcut for `array_push` would be:

```
foreach($orders as $order) {
    $list[] = array(
        $order['name'],
        $order['email'],
        (boolean) $order['buyer_accepts_marketing']
    );
}
```

I generally find that it looks nicer  :)

If you want to do more complex logic to get your boolean value you could create a new variable for it:

```
foreach($orders as $order) {
    $buyer_accepts_marketing = false;
    if( $order['buyer_accepts_marketing'] ) $buyer_accepts_marketing = true;

    array_push($list, array(
        $order['name'],
        $order['email'],
        $buyer_accepts_marketing
    ));
}
```

If you want to instead set your `buyer_accepts_marketing` value to a string value of "true" or "false", then do:

```
foreach($orders as $order) {
    $buyer_accepts_marketing = "false";
    if( $order['buyer_accepts_marketing'] ) $buyer_accepts_marketing = "true";

    array_push($list, array(
        $order['name'],
        $order['email'],
        $buyer_accepts_marketing
    ));
}
```

Just be aware that a string "true" is not boolean, nor is "false".  For example:

```
if( "true" == true ) echo "It's true";
```

Will echo "It's true".  However, so will:

```
if( "false" == true ) echo "It's true";
```

That's because any string that isn't set to `"0"` or `""` will evaluate as true.

Comment: I also had similar problem some time back. I checked with same code as you mentioned above but this code still gives value as "1" when array is printed. I tried both of your codes.

Comment: @Purushottamzende How are you printing the array?

Comment: Using "print_r". I also tried by saving them in DB and also by displaying it in string, but no success.

Comment: @Purushottamzende use var_dump to print this array

Comment: @cully: All your answers i tried, but it seems to be nothing happen. Any other way? Thank you.

Comment: @Purushottamzende `print_r` doesn't seem to explicitly acknowledge booleans, but it it is in fact a boolean.  See this example:  http://codepad.org/5fzAbKO8

Comment: @user3667492 It works.  See http://codepad.org/5fzAbKO8  If you are using `print_r` to output the result, it will show up as a `1`, but the value is actually boolean.

Comment: @CullyLarson Yes, using var_dump for array will show type as "boolean" which is correct, but my requirement was to show true or false instead of 1 or 0 to the user. So lastly is used string "true / false" for this.

Comment: @Purushottamzende A boolean cast to a string (which is what happens if you just put a boolean into a string) will result in a 1 or a 0.  If you want to show true/false, you need to do something like `echo ($myvar) ? "true" : "false";`

Comment: @CullyLarson: It will printed as 1 know?. I want as true, If 1 mean true, else false.

Comment: @user3667492 Look at the very bottom where I'm setting the value to `"true"` or `"false"`

Comment: @CullyLarson: How to add this in my code?.. Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: @user3667492 Just copy and paste it.  It's the code your provided, just modified a bit.  It still uses the same variables, etc. that you use.  By the way, I'm not talking about the link I sent in a previous comment, I'm talking about the last example in my answer, with a `foreach` loop.

Comment: @CullyLarson: I got it, I simply use, if( $order['buyer_accepts_marketing'] ){ 
       $buyer_accepts_marketing = "true";
}.. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @user3667492 That won't work if the value is false.  Have you looked at my last example in the answer?

Comment: @CullyLarson: if( $order['buyer_accepts_marketing'] ){ $buyer_accepts_marketing = "true"; } else { $buyer_accepts_marketing = "false"; }.. Now ok?.. Yes, i have seen your answer.

Comment: @user3667492 Try it and see  :)

Comment: @CullyLarson: I tried, and i have only values 1, and have no '0' value.. If i get '0' value means, will get false right?

Comment: @CullyLarson; I just confused, and i tried your code, but seems to be nothing happen, please help me?..

Comment: @user3667492 It should just work.  See this example:  http://codepad.org/HZM5F4S8

Comment: @CullyLarson: if $order['buyer_accepts_marketing'] value will be 0 or  empty (null) it will not enter in condition right?.

Comment: No, it will be set to "false".  If this example isn't clear enough, I don't know what else I can do for you  http://codepad.org/1JsxlvZE

Comment: @CullyLarson: $buyer_accepts_marketing = "false";
    if( $order['buyer_accepts_marketing'] ) { $buyer_accepts_marketing = "true"; }.. Is it correct?.

Comment: @CullyLarson: I have an one doubt? Can  you help?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
foreach($orders as $order) {
if( $order['buyer_accepts_marketing'] ){ 
       $buyer_accepts_marketing = "true";
}
$list[] = array(
        $order['name'],
        $order['email'],
        $buyer_accepts_marketing; 
    );
}
```

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @ railsbox: I have an one doubt, in your answer, $order['buyer_accepts_marketing'] value is whatever it is, it will display as true right?..

Comment: @user3667492 if $order['buyer_accepts_marketing'] value will be 0 aur empty (null) it will not enter in condition

Comment: Thanks again!:). but if it is 0 , I will get false.. Can you help me?.